# How to store the content of a tl-var without further expansion

Tags: expansion, expl3

I would like to retrieve the content of expl3-variables e.g. for values of property lists. The variable names can contain special chars, so it should work with c-types. I can do it like this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
 \tl_new:c {l_uf_some!special!name_tl } 
 \tl_set:cn{l_uf_some!special!name_tl }{special \blub abc }

 \tl_new:N \l_uf_some_tl 
 \tl_set:Nn\l_uf_some_tl {xxx\blub abc }

 \prop_new:N \l_uf_some_prop
 \prop_put:Nnx\l_uf_some_prop {some}        { some~text~\exp_args:No \exp_not:n { \l_uf_some_tl } }
 \prop_put:Nnx\l_uf_some_prop {somespecial} { some~text~\exp_args:Nc \exp_not:o { l_uf_some!special!name_tl } }
 \prop_show:N \l_uf_some_prop

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

This outputs on the terminal exactly what I want:

```
The property list \l_uf_some_prop contains the pairs (without outer braces):
>  {some}  =>  {some text xxx\blub abc}
>  {somespecial}  =>  {some text special\blub abc}.
```

But I'm not quite happy with the `\exp_args:No \exp_not:n` / `\exp_args:Nc \exp_not:o`. Before I write a `\uf_get_tl:N/c` is there something better built-in that I missed until now?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No, then \blub is a string and no longer an command. I don't want to change catcodes of the content, the result should be identical to `\prop_put:Nnn\l_uf_some_prop{some}{xxx \blub abc}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the content of a (tl-)**v**ariable, while **not** **exp**anding it, you can use `\exp_not:V`. The equivalent to `c`-types for `V`-types are `v`-type arguments:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
 \tl_new:c {l_uf_some!special!name_tl } 
 \tl_set:cn{l_uf_some!special!name_tl }{special \blub abc }

 \tl_new:N \l_uf_some_tl 
 \tl_set:Nn\l_uf_some_tl {xxx\blub abc }

 \prop_new:N \l_uf_some_prop
 \prop_put:Nnx\l_uf_some_prop {some}        { some~text~\exp_not:V\l_uf_some_tl }
 \prop_put:Nnx\l_uf_some_prop {somespecial} { some~text~\exp_not:v{ l_uf_some!special!name_tl } }
 \prop_show:N \l_uf_some_prop

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Output:

```
The property list \l_uf_some_prop contains the pairs (without outer braces):
>  {some}  =>  {some text xxx\blub abc}
>  {somespecial}  =>  {some text special\blub abc}.
```

Comment: Also `\exp_not:o { \l_uf_some_tl }` would work, but `\exp_not:V` is conceptually better, in particular for the “csname” variant `\exp_not:v`. There's a small remark to make: usually, `V` variants brace the result, but `\exp_not:V` doesn't.

Comment: Oh my god. I had really a blind point here ... I always stopped to read at the `\exp_not:n`.